# Strange result from a subquery in my trigger SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, subquery

Hello consider the following tables

`PassedCourses`:

```
id     code    credits
----------------------
frosto  CON002  10
oskjone CON002  10
tegman  CON002  10
oskjon  LAN001  10
oskjon  TDA300  10
oskjon  TDA357  8
oskjone TDA357  8
oskjon  TDA400  8
oskjon  TDA416  10
```

and

`Prerequisites`:

```
code    prereq
---------------
TDA301  TDA300
TDA301  TDA357
CON001  CON002
LAN003  LAN002
```

Code is the code for a specific course and prereq is the code for the prerequired course to code. In trigger I want to be able to create a variable

```
stdhasntprereq INT
```

Now consider the following subquery

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
INTO StdHasntPrereq
FROM 
    (SELECT *
     FROM Prerequisites Pr
     WHERE :newLine.code = Pr.code) Prere
LEFT JOIN
    PassedCourses P ON P.cid = :newline.cid 
                    AND Prere.prereq = P.code
                    AND P.code IS NULL;
```

Now if I were to insert this student the trigger will activate

```
insert into REGISTRATIONS (CID, CODE, STATUS)
values ('oskjon', 'TDA301', 'Registered');
```

Finally for the question: in my calculations the subquery above should be giving me no rows and therefore `Stdhasntprereq` should be = 0 (in other words it would be false for the student to NOT have passed the prerequisites).

However it is = 2. Can somebody please explain to me why this is and how to make it = 0?

Comment: What happens if you move `P.code IS NULL` to a `where` clause?

Comment: How would that look like?

Answer (score 0):

It's 2 because you are doing a LEFT JOIN, which always succeeds, without any filtering.

To count the number of prereq courses *not* passed, try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
INTO StdHasntPrereq
FROM Prerequisites r
LEFT JOIN PassedCourses p ON p.code = r.code
WHERE r.code = :newLine.code
AND p.code IS NULL
```

Note the where clause condition `p.code IS NULL` (which you erroneously have *within* an inner query), which filters out successful joins - leaving only the missing prerequisite courses.